# Highcharts using JSON - graph not displaying mysql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have been able to produce results from mysql using:

```
$myArray=array();
$tempArray = array();

// Get all records
while ( $row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
}
echo json_encode($myArray);

$mysqli->close();

 ?>
```

And I then included this to produce a chart on my page index.php by using the following Javascript.

what concepts/code am I not understanding/missing to produce a chart based upon my ajax json?

**EDITED - SOLUTION:**

Final PHP code to produce the json:

```
while ( $row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{   

    $tempArray[0] = $row['unix_timestamp(auct.end_date)'];
    $tempArray[0] *= 1000;
    $tempArray[1] = $row['winning_bid'];

    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);

}
echo json_encode ($myArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$mysqli->close();

 ?>
```

Final javascript code:

```
$('#btn_search').click(function(){
    txt_search = $('#txt_search').val();
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: './php/search.php',  
      type: 'GET',
      data: {search: txt_search}, 
      dataType: 'json',                   
      success: function(rows)      
      {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chartdiv',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 100,
                marginBottom: 50
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Whisky Tracking',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                text: 'EndDate',
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Price',
                    color: '#CC680E'
                }, 
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 20,
                    color: '#CC680E'
                }]
            },
            series: [{
            name:  txt_search,
            xAxis:0,
            data: rows,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                    return '£'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                    }
                }
            }],         

        });
      }
    }); 
    goToByScroll('tracker');
    return false;
});
```

Sample Data from the JSON:

```
[1306732000000,160],[1306745000000,45],[1306788000000,65],[1306788000000,50],[1306712000000,130],[1306733000000,240],[1306744000000,60],[1306788000000,250],[1306710000000,145]
```

Comment: What is not working? Have you got the div for chartdiv on the page?

Comment: Yes - sorry it doesn't display any data (guessing the array is the problem).  The chart displays but with no data

Comment: What do you expect it to show? At the moment it looks like you have three different rows in the JSON so how do you plan to show all three on the y axis?

Comment: I am not interested in the name coloumn but rather the winning on the Y axis and the date on the x axis - sorry I should have included that to

Comment: Created a new answer with more accurate information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that values are strings, for example, your data:

```
["2011-05-30 00:00:00","130"]
```

Should be instead:

```
[1306706400000, 130]
```

To it's timestamp in ms and true value.

You can read about `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option for `json_encode(string, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)` to change strings to numbers. But dates to timestamps you need to change on your own.

Edit:
Also the problem was with setting data in doubled array, changed from:

```
data: [rows]
```

to:

```
data: rows
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried amending the query to return the datetime column as UNIX_TIMESTAMP but that didn't work.  It did change the graph but not anything like I would expect (simply extended the Y-AXIS ranges).  Am I right in thinking the first element in the array is the  x-axis and the second the y-axis?

Comment: Indeed, first element is x-value, second is y-value. Make sure you have not set categories in xAxis. Also, could you attach to the question example of actual returnej JSON? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited it above, I read something that suggested UNIX_TIMESTAMP required to be divided by 1000 to bring it into line with Javascript...thanks for the info regarding the xy

Comment: Not dividing, multiplying.. ;) Why have you changed order of elements?

Comment: I am going in circles, keep reading posts which are not fully related and I don't understand the changes I make...grrr.  Anyway I've attached a screenshot of what the chart looks like.. I am switching the order back - but the y-axis looks to be using the timstamp?

Comment: h, very good point. I am silly, the query I am using to view the json may contain some records with exactly the same timestamp (records are populated every month with the same date for that month) however I expect the results to be more like the JSON attached above (I am following this up on the forum as I've got myself so stuck/confused) - I appreciate the patience. to ask direct question, I have multiplied the date by 1000 but it has increased the y-axis value, even though it is the first element?!?!

Comment: Fixed it - such a pain. Ultimately the problem was data: [rows], changing it to  data: rows, works.  Should I post an answer detailing the full steps or shall you just add that to yours and I can tick it.  Worth noting I did this to edit the timestamp:$tempArray[0] = $row['unix_timestamp(auct.end_date)'];
$tempArray[0] *= 1000;

Comment: Updated answer, you should put your code at the beginning, like you did at forum ;)